# How to transfer SQL variable back into ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, sql

I am trying to teach myself to access sql tables from an ArcPy script as part of a larger QC process. I am fairly certain that I have the sql statement correct (it works in SQL Server, albeit formatted a little differently), but I have no clue how to return my declared sql variable back as a python variable so that I may run other stuff on it.

I am trying to check a sql table in an ArcSDE Database where the value of a single column is smaller than 1000 and larger than 10. If there are values outside this range, I need to run other processes.

This is what I've got so far:

```
SDE = r'Database Connections\NC_RISK - 106.sde'
SQLLink = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(SDE)
L_HAZARDPROBABILITY = r'\NC_RISK.sql.L_HAZARDPROBABILITY'

sql = '''DECLARE @MyBadIndicator int; SET @MyBadIndicator = 0; SET @MyBadIndicator = SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT L_HAZARDPROBABILITY.F_EVENT
    FROM L_HAZARDPROBABILITY WHERE L_HAZARDPROBABILITY.F_EVENT<10 Or L_HAZARDPROBABILITY.F_EVENT >1000)'''
```

How do a get the value of MyBadIndicator so that ArcPy can use it?

Comment: ODBC doesn't really consider variables to be valid objects (in fact, they didn't exist when ODBC was created).  You need to make a *query* which returns a *row* to interact with ArcGIS.